# How to use same backend (django) api cookie to frontend(vuejs)?

Tags: django, vue.js, cookies, jwt

I've got confusion when dealing with cookies on frontend vs backend.

I've a cookie generated in backend  as

```
class JWTAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')

        if not token:
            return None
        try:
            payload = jwt.decode(token, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms=['HS256'])
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('unauthenticated')
        user = get_user_model().objects.filter(id=payload['id']).first()
        if user is None:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("Unauthenticated")
        return (user, None)
```

When i use login in frontend vuejs, a cookie is generated through api , which cookie is a also added by frontend and marked as httpOnly .
I want to use same cookie without making new one in frontend.

In frontend When I console.log `document.cookie` the generated cookie is not available , although it shows cookies generated, but at same time at backend when i access api and see `console.log(document.cookie)`  it is available there.

How can i access access that cookie even in frontend, through vuejs/javascript through `document.cookie` , so that i can do authentication and global guards in frontend.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i've found my answer.
For enabling cookie same as backend to frontend,  I've to look into views.py while setting up cookie in backend and set response  to httpOnly False.

```
response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=False)
```

Now , I'm able to use document.cookie in frontend too.